# Cannot Parse JSON in UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I created an application on UWP whose data is parsed to JSON with JSON as below:

[JSON](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U8BJcssi2AxrZTg56)

I'm having trouble parsing json on "jawaban" and an error message appears like below:
[image: error message]

Code:

```
JsonArray jsonDataOption = groupObjectSoal["jawaban"].GetArray();
                                    foreach (JsonValue groupValueOption in jsonDataSoal)
                                    {
                                        JsonObject groupObjectOption = groupValueSoal.GetObject();

                                        string oid = groupObjectOption["oid"].GetString();
                                        string option = groupObjectOption["q_option"].GetString();
                                        string score = groupObjectOption["score"].GetString();

                                        QuizOption pilihan = new QuizOption();
                                        pilihan.OID = oid;
                                        pilihan.Option = option;
                                        pilihan.Score = score;
                                    }
```

How to handle it?

Note:

For the full code, can be seen [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7lo22fdNppsDQpBT)

Comment: Have you tried json.net?

Answer (score 3):

Property "list_soal" contains an array with two elements. The first element does not have property "jawaban", so your code fails on parsing first element

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.net

[Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
There are plenty examples on the site.
It will automatically fill your data model.

You can deserialize to object by calling.

```
YourObject m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(json);
```

where json is your json string and YourObject is your model